# Limitar uma tabela com o limite da pagina de impressão

Tags: php, html, laravel

Boa tarde, Sou novato na programação e estou testando algumas coisinhas hehehe.

Gostaria de saber se é possível gerar uma tabela limitada com espaços vazios (conforme a imagem) que o limite seria o tamanho da página de impressão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atualmente eu faço um loop dentro dos dados e exibe na tabela, porem já é definido mais 40 linhas com campos vazios, somente para a ocupação.

```
@foreach($testes->sortBy('created') as $teste)
          <tr class="row3">
            <td class="column0 style6 null" style="padding:3px">{{data_brasil($teste->created)}}</td>
            <td class="column1 style1 null" style="padding:3px">{{$teste->nome ?? "Não Definido"}}</td>
            <td class="column2 style1 null" style="padding:3px"></td>
            <td class="column3 style1 null" style="padding:3px">{{$teste->numero}}</td>
            <td class="column4 style1 null" style="padding:3px"></td>
            <td class="column5 style1 null" style="padding:3px"></td>
            <td class="column6 style1 null" style="padding:3px"></td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach
      <tr class="row4">
        <td class="column0 style6 null"></td>
        <td class="column1 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column2 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column3 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column4 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column5 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column6 style1 null"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row5">
        <td class="column0 style6 null"></td>
        <td class="column1 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column2 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column3 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column4 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column5 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column6 style1 null"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row45">
        <td class="column0 style6 null"></td>
        <td class="column1 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column2 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column3 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column4 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column5 style1 null"></td>
        <td class="column6 style1 null"></td>
      </tr>
```

Resumindo a pergunta: Há como limitar a tabela pela folha de impressão? e se tem um nome específico para essa ação?

Ps: Não localizei uma pergunta que me ajudou nesse caso.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira pergunta, você está usando o eloquent para a consulta?
Se sim você pode limitar a quantidade de itens de várias formas, aconselho usar o limit() ou paginate(). O limit limita a quantidade de registros da consulta sql. Ex:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->offset(10)
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

O paginate no qual eu recomendo fortemente é usado em paginações, você seta a quantidade de itens que deseja receber por página e passa o número da página no QueryString na requisição
Ex:

```
Na url da requisição Get passe a variável page contendo a página desejada (querystring). 
Ex: http://example.com/admin/users?page=1
```

E na consulta passe a quantidade de itens por página:

```
'users' => DB::table('users')->paginate(15)
```

Dessa forma você pode passar a página atual do seu documento e buscar somente a quantidade informada por página

Comment: Não sabia dessa funcionalidade, e funcionou muito bem, obg!